# Issues understanding ProgressBar

Tags: powershell, progress-bar

I have a script that I need to insert GUI style progress bar into, specifically at the end of it. The script is for automated account creation. What I am having an issue understand is how to insert different messages into the box, example at 15 seconds "Creating Account" would display in the progress bar, at 30 seconds, "Setting ACL" would display and so on. Below is what I have so far, I might need to take it in a different direction.

```
$ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$ProgressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$ProgressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,10)
$ProgressBar.Name = "ProgressBar"
$objForm.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)
```

I was able to get the progress bar below to show correctly but I was not able to write what process, example at 10% " Creating User" would be written to the bar. Any help?

```
 bFunction UpdateProgressBar{

# Divide the number of items processed so far by the total number of items to process, then times it by 100
$Progress = $Global:ProgressCurrent /$Global:ProgressTotal*100

# Update the ProgressBar value
$ProgressBar.Value = $Progress
```

}

function TestBar
{
    # Create basic form

```
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$objForm.StartPosition = 1
$objForm.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,50)
$objForm.Name = "Form1"
$objForm.Text = "Example ProgressBar"
$objForm.Label = for ($i = 1; $i -le 100; $i++)
                    {Write-Progress -Activity "Testing" -Status "$i% Complete:" -PercentComplete $i;}

$ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$ProgressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$ProgressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,10)
$ProgressBar.Name = "ProgressBar"
$objForm.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)

$objForm.ShowDialog() | out-Null
```

}
TestBar

Comment: Couldn't you just add a label to your form and update text messages there?

Comment: Not sure what you understand jradich, when I attempt to add a label I just get an error that the 'Label' property cannot be found.